# How do I make the most of Evasion?

Tags: desktop-dungeons

There are a number of ways to gain Evasion in Desktop Dungeons, but one class, the Rogue, has a permanent +20% evasion chance. As far as I can tell, this means that monsters have a 20% chance to miss me.

Is there a way I can predict when this will occur to take full advantage of it? How can I make the most of this ability?

Comment: It occasionally gives you some free health, but since it is unpredictable, I agree that it tends to be not very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a lot of tiles left to reveal, you can use it to try the first attack over and over (revealing tiles and healing each time) until you get a free hit.  Coupled with something like first strike/slow, death protection, you can get 3 extra hits off enemies for free, which you can probably use to kill an enemy 3+ levels above.